# How to 10 second forward or backward in Spotify player

Tags: ios, swift, spotify, duration

I am trying to add(move forward) 10 second song duration or minus(move backward) 10 second in Spotify player but i am really confused how to add or minus.

When i m trying to use this code the song is not changed duration

```
// forward button action 
@IBAction func moveFrdBtnAction(_ sender: Any) {
  SpotifyManager.shared.audioStreaming(SpotifyManager.shared.player, didSeekToPosition: TimeInterval(10))
}

// spotify delegate method seekToPosition
func audioStreaming(_ audioStreaming: SPTAudioStreamingController!, didSeekToPosition position: TimeInterval) {
    player?.seek(to: position, callback: { (error) in
        let songDuration = audioStreaming.metadata.currentTrack?.duration as Any as! Double
        self.delegate?.getSongTime(timeCount: Int(songDuration)+1)
    })
}
```

We are making a music application using the same SDK in both the platforms (Android & iOS), the seekToPosition method of the Spotify SDK is working correctly in the Android version, however, it is not working in the iOS one.The delegate method calls itself but the music stops.

Can you kindly let us know why this scenario is happening, and what should we do to run it on the iOS devices as well.

Can someone please explain to me how to solve this , i've tried to solve this  but no results yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't call delegate methods of object declared by some protocol by yourself. Instead, you can see that you can call code from `audioStreaming(_:didSeekToPosition:)` inside `moveFrdBtnAction(_:)`

Comment: ya @RobertDresler using two different class one is player class and second one spotify class in spotify class took a variable and use like delegate with help of shared

Answer (score 1):

I don't use this API so my answer will be based your code and Spotify's [reference documentation](https://spotify.github.io/ios-streaming-sdk/hierarchy.html).

I think there are a few things wrong with your flow:

1. As [Robert Dresler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10253094/robert-dresler) commented, you should (approximately) never call a delegate directly, a delegate calls you.
2. I'm pretty sure your action currently results in jumping **to** exactly 10 seconds, not **by** 10 seconds.

(As an aside, I'd *suggest* changing the name of your function `moveFrdBtnAction` to at least add more vowels)

Anyway, here's my best guess at what you want:

```swift
// forward button action 
@IBAction func moveForwardButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
   skipAudio(by: 10)
}

@IBAction func moveBackButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
   skipAudio(by: -10)
}

func skipAudio(by interval: TimeInterval) {
   if let player = player {
      let position = player.playbackState.position // The documentation alludes to milliseconds but examples don't.
         player.seek(to: position + interval, callback: { (error) in
         // Handle the error (if any)
      })
   }
}

// spotify delegate method seekToPosition
func audioStreaming(_ audioStreaming: SPTAudioStreamingController!, didSeekToPosition position: TimeInterval) {
   // Update your UI
}
```

Note that I have not handled seeking before the start of the track, nor after the end which could happen with a simple `position + interval`. The API may handle this for you, or not.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but when i m trying this code again player hanged and return no response, audio stop

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the examples here: [spotify/ios-sdk](https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk). In the [NowPlayingView example](https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk/blob/master/DemoProjects/NowPlayingView/NowPlayingView/ViewController.swift) they use the '[seekForward15Seconds](https://spotify.github.io/ios-sdk/html/Protocols/SPTAppRemotePlayerAPI.html#//api/name/seekForward15Seconds:)', maybe you could use that? If you still need 10s I have added a function below. The position is in milliseconds.

> "position:    The position to seek to in milliseconds" 
>   [docs](https://spotify.github.io/ios-sdk/html/Protocols/SPTAppRemotePlayerAPI.html#//api/name/seekToPosition:callback:)

**ViewController.swift**

```
var appRemote: SPTAppRemote {
    get {
        return AppDelegate.sharedInstance.appRemote
    }
}

fileprivate func seekForward15Seconds() {
    appRemote.playerAPI?.seekForward15Seconds(defaultCallback)
}

fileprivate seekBackward15Seconds() {
    appRemote.playerAPI?.seekBackward15Seconds(defaultCallback)
}

// TODO: Or you could try this function
func seekForward(seconds: Int){
    appRemote.playerAPI?.getPlayerState({ (result, error) in
        // playback position in milliseconds
        let current_position = self.playerState?.playbackPosition
        let seconds_in_milliseconds = seconds * 1000

        self.appRemote.playerAPI?.seek(toPosition: current_position + seconds_in_milliseconds, callback: { (result, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                print(error)
                return
            }
        })
    })
}

var defaultCallback: SPTAppRemoteCallback {
        get {
            return {[weak self] _, error in
                if let error = error {
                    self?.displayError(error as NSError)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
lazy var appRemote: SPTAppRemote = {
        let configuration = SPTConfiguration(clientID: self.clientIdentifier, redirectURL: self.redirectUri)
        let appRemote = SPTAppRemote(configuration: configuration, logLevel: .debug)
        appRemote.connectionParameters.accessToken = self.accessToken
        appRemote.delegate = self
        return appRemote
    }()

    class var sharedInstance: AppDelegate {
        get {
            return UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        }
    }
```

**Edit1:**

For this to work you need to follow the [Prepare Your Environment](https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk#prepare-your-environment):

> [image: framwork]
>
> Add the SpotifyiOS.framework to your Xcode project

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your reply but when i m trying this code give me some error like: 1.Use of undeclared type 'SPTAppRemoteCallback' , 2. Use of undeclared type 'SPTAppRemote'

Comment: @ShamDass look at the link I attached on how to get the demo up and running: https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk#prepare-your-environment

Comment: Okay Thank you very much  i will try

Comment: @ShamDass If you find the time, please share the progress.

Comment: @ShamDass okey, did you try the `seekForward15Seconds` function ?

Comment: Yes. but same problem